# Abbott's Understanding Analysis Theorem 3.2.8: Proof Check

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove Theorem 3.2.8 from Abbott's Understanding Analysis (2nd ed) which states that:
*Theorem 3.2.8:  A set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed if and only if every Cauchy sequence contained in $F$ has a limit that is also an element of $F$.*
Here is my attempt at the proof which uses theorem 3.2.5 (A point $x$ is the limit point of a set $A$ if and only if $x = lim~a_n$ for some sequence $(a_n)$ contained in $A$ satisfying $a_n \neq x~ ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$)
*Proof:* ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $F$ is closed and let $X$ be a set of all limit points and $X \subseteq F$. Suppose $x_k \in X$. To generate a Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$, consider $\epsilon = 1/n$ such that
$$
a_n \in V_{1/n}(x_k) \cap F \setminus \{x_k \}
$$
From theorem 3.2.5, $a_n \to x_k$ and since $x_k \in F$, $\Rightarrow$ is thus proved.
To prove ($\Leftarrow$), suppose ($a_n$) is a Cauchy sequence. Also suppose $x$ is the *limit point* of $F$. Since ($a_n$) is Cauchy, it is convergent and so from theorem 3.2.5, $x = lim~a_n$. Since, $x \in F$, this proves ($\Leftarrow$).

I would appreciate if someone can critique my proof writing and suggest if this proof is correct and rigourous

Comment: In second part when $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, if you know, that $x = lim~a_n$, how you know before it, that "$x$ is the limit point of $F$"?

Comment: The direction $\implies$ is not right because you are imposing a kind of Cauchy sequence around a point, but you must prove the result for any Cauchy sequence. So you must start from an arbitrary Cauchy sequence in $F$, say $(x_n)$, and prove that there is some $x\in F$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$.

Comment: the other direction doesnt seem right either or the wording is confuse: any Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$ converges in $F$, and now you need to prove that $F$ is closed, that is, that it contains all it limit points.

Comment: This is an peculiar fact to emphasize a rigorous proof of, as it follows immediately from Cauchy sequences having (unique) limits in complete spaces and the equivalence between the characterization of closed sets as those which contain their boundary, both rather fundamental facts.